# Deserializing azure keyvault secret json to MicrosoftIdentityOptions

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, azure-keyvault, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I load the keyvault secrets when the app starts and the configuration has the vault secrets added
[as we can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4rIr.png).
I am using the Microsoft.Identity.Web for adding the AD SSO and registers the AddSignin() as mentioned in the samples. But the secret is not getting serialized as expected [at this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgrNY.png). However if the secrets are kept in appsettings.json it works fine. How can I make this work? An explicit deserialization is required?

Please find below the entire code setup

1.Program.cs has the below code.

```
ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingCtx, config) =>
        {

            if (hostingCtx.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
            {
                var builtConfig = config.Build();
                AzureKeyVaultConfigurationExtensions.AddAzureKeyVault(config, builtConfig["AppConfiguration:KeyVaultUrl"]);
            }
        })
```

2. The secret in the below json format is stored in keyvault

```
{"CallbackPath":"/home/index","ClientId":"######","ClientSecret":"#######","Domain":"######","Instance":"######","TenantId":"######"}
```

3. Added a reference to Microsoft.Identity.Web
4. Registered the below service in Startup.cs->ConfigureService

```
    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
                {
                    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddSignIn("AzureAd1", configuration, options => configuration.Bind("AzureAd1", options));
```

5. On application bootstrap the below variable **microsoftIdentityOptions**  is null

File - WebAppServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddSignIn(
                this AuthenticationBuilder builder,
                string configSectionName,
                IConfiguration configuration,
                string openIdConnectScheme,
                string cookieScheme,
                Action<OpenIdConnectOptions> configureOptions,
                bool subscribeToOpenIdConnectMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents = false)
            {
                builder.Services.Configure(openIdConnectScheme, configureOptions);
                builder.Services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>(options => configuration.Bind(configSectionName, options));

                var microsoftIdentityOptions = configuration.GetSection(configSectionName).Get<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>();
     .......
     ......
    }
```

Any help deeply appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: We need to see the actual code.  All the relevant code to they point where we can replicate this on our own.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro, please let know if you need more details.

Comment: As an increment, in case you need to customize any OIDC or JWT event, we have it documented at: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/customization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is right here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2#bind-an-array-to-a-class

> Create secrets in the key vault as name-value pairs.
>
> Azure Key Vault secret names are limited to alphanumeric characters and dashes. Hierarchical values (configuration sections) use -- (two dashes) as a separator. Colons, which are normally used to delimit a section from a subkey in ASP.NET Core configuration, aren't allowed in key vault secret names. Therefore, two dashes are used and swapped for a colon when the secrets are loaded into the app's configuration.

Instead of keeping all the secrets inside a single json, each property should be added as a single secret.

For eg "AzureAd1--TenantId" should be the name of the key where AzureAd1 denotes the section